# to add scrollbar within window

Tags: javascript

I have 3 accordions in a same page.On the above of accordion there is header page.I want that headerpage should become still and on the part of accordions a scrollbar is there.so that when i scroll the page only inner page get scrolled instead of whole page .suggest using javascript

Comment: Have you looked into JScrollPane?

Comment: did you try `overflow-y:scroll` on the container?

Comment: alternatively you can position your "header" absolutely when the you begin to scroll down. This requires JS. overflow doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer jquery this is a good option   **jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js**

for something more surf this link too [link](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)